# Uma expressao regular para detectar siglas de rodovias brasileiras

Tags: regex, entrada-de-dados

Estou tentando detectar se um determinado endereço corresponde a uma rodovia brasileira.

Por exemplo, `br-101` corresponde.

Meu plano inicial era listar as siglas de estados (mg, sp, rn ...) mais a sigla br, e escrever algo como `/sigla1-[0-9]{3}|sigla2-[0-9]{3}.../`.

Mas uma consulta a wikipedia me rendeu uma surpresa: há outros prefixos além dos estados. (por exemplo, `prc`, em https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodovias_do_Paran%C3%A1)

Pergunto, então: Qual a forma mais correta de detectar as rodovias?

Podemos pegar `(duas_ou_tres_letras)-(tres_numeros)`, por exemplo. A parte antes do hifen tem necessariamente duas ou três letras? a parte depois do hifem pode ter menos do que três números?

Alguém teria por acaso uma lista das possiveis siglas que podem vir antes do hifen?

Comment: Parece-se que o padrão `2|3 letras - 3 números` é válido. Consegue fazer?

Comment: Sim, sim. Meu problema não é escrever a reg exp, mas sim saber qual criterio é o mais rasoavel. Se existisse, eu estaria perguntando no stack overflow DER, não no de programacao...

Answer (score 2):

Achei interessante a pergunta e procurei me informar como funciona a nomenclatura das rodovias do Brasil.

Segundo o site [rodovias federais do governo](http://www.infraestrutura.pr.gov.br/modules/conteudo/conteudo.php?conteudo=187) há um padrão para definição dos nomes das rodovias federais. E pelo o eu [pesquisei](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_rodovias_do_Brasil) pude perceber que este padrão também é adotados nas rodovias estaduais, mas há exceções.

O primeiro número do nome da rodovia, por exemplo, BR-**3**07 tem significado e varia do 0 ao 6. E também aplica-se as rodovias estaduais.

- Rodovias radiais: BR-0xx - rodovias que partem da capital federal em direção aos extremos do país
- Rodovias longitudinais: BR-1xx - rodovias que cortam o país na
  direção norte-sul
- Rodovias transversais: BR-2xx - rodovias que cortam o país na direção
  leste-oeste
- Rodovias diagonais: BR-3xx - rodovias podem apresentar dois modos de
  orientação: noroeste-sudeste ou nordeste-sudoeste
- Rodovias de ligação: BR-4xx - rodovias apresentam-se em qualquer
  direção. Também há rodovias iniciadas com BR-6xx, porém são poucas e
  de curta extensão.

Seria interessante confirmar estas informações para que a regex seja mais precisa, Por exemplo:

- Sabemos que as primeiras informações são letras maiúsculas e variam
  de 2 a 3 letras: `[A-Z]{2,3}`
- Há um hífen entre as letras e os números: `-`
- O primeiro número varia de 0 à 6: `[0-6]`
- E termina com mais dois dígitos: `[0-9]{2}`

Por fim sua regex ficaria assim: `[A-Z]{2,3}-[0-6][0-9]{2}`.
[Exemplo funcional](https://regex101.com/r/xrpiWQ/1)

Answer (score 1):

Você pode montar duas regex uma mais genéricas para validar apenas o formato da rodovia e outra mais especializada que garante com maior chances a sua existencia.

Pela pesquisa que fiz algumas rodovias recebe um `C` após a sigla do estado pois são coincidentes ou seja um trecho de um rodovia federal está no mesmo trecho de uma estadual e é responsabilidade do estado manter a conservação porém não encontrei nenhuma lista centralizada cada está mantem sua prórpia lista.

Nem todos os estados possuem rodovia coincidentes logo a segunda regex casa valores inválidos como BRC-000 ou ACC-00 então é necessário um tratamento adicional na aplicação como um lista exceções ou descobrir quais estados tem essas rodovias e refinar mais regex.

A generica seria:

```
[A-Z]{2,3}-[0-9]{3}
```

Entradas:

```
BR-101 //OK
ABC-100 //OK
ZZ-000 //OK
```

[Exemplo - regex101](https://regex101.com/r/shT3cr/1/)

A outra seria a lista de siglas dos estados seguida de um `C` de coincidente opcional seguido de traço e três números.

```
(AC|AL|AP|AM|BA|CE|DF|ES|GO|MA|MT|MS|MG|PA|PB|PR|PE|PI|RJ|RN|RS|RO|RR|SC|SP|SE|TO|BR)C?-[0-9]{3}
```

Entradas:

```
BR-101 //OK
ABC-000 //fora do padrão
ZZZ-999 //fora do padrão
PRC-280 //OK
RSC-453 //OK
BRC-000 //OK mas é inválida
ACC-999 //OK mas é inválida
```

[Exemplo - regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zGasIC/1)

Comment: E por quê não fazer na mesma?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a primeira serve para validar o formato apenas, já a segunda é mais especifica mais próxima da realidade. Como eu escrevi deu a entender que precisa das duas? qualquer coisa já reviso

Comment: Não como uma questão de necessidade, mas é que deixando o terceiro caractere opcional, ele casará com os nomes genéricos também, por isso questionei o fato de utilizar as duas e não apenas uma.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss editei a resposta se tiver mais alguma observação avise.